# How to make installed cordova plugins work in an HTML page in SD card?

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins

I came to notice that all the installed plugins works perfectly if the HTML pages are inside www folder. But if the app is navigated to an HTML page inside an SD card the installed plugins don't work.

For eg:-

```
   window.plugins.toast.show("Success...");
```

does not work. I tried initializing the plugin by using:

```
   cordova.require();
```

But still it didn't work. Please help me in resolving this. Thanks in advance to all the sugestions :-)